# PHP: What's the point of UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE?

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling

The PHP manual has a section called [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). That section has a subsection called [Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). That subsection describes an error called "UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE":

Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in *php.ini*.

However, in my experience, it's impossible to ever check for this particular error using UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE because if a user ever does upload a file that exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini, the $_FILES superglobal is empty. Want to test it for yourself? Save this as "upload_test.php" and then try to upload a file that's under the limit and then a file that's over the limit:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['submitted']) && $_GET['submitted'] === 'true')
    {
        echo 'Contents of $_POST:<hr><pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre><hr>Contents of $_FILES:<hr><pre>';
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo '</pre><hr>';
        exit;
    }

    $max_filesize_in_mib = min((int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')), (int)(ini_get('post_max_size')), (int)(ini_get('memory_limit')));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>PHP Upload Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload a File (Maximum File Size: <?php echo $max_filesize_in_mib; ?> MiB)</h1>
        <form action="upload_test.php?submitted=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="upload_test">
            <input type="hidden" name="random_field" value="You should see this field in the $_POST superglobal.">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is this: what's the point of UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE if you can never check for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

This make sense when your `POST_MAX_SIZE` is bigger than `UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE`.

I tried in an environment where `POST_MAX_SIZE` is `128MB`, then i set `UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE` to `1MB`

Here's what i got (as expected):

```
Contents of $_POST:
Array
(
    [random_field] => You should see this field in the $_POST superglobal.
)

Contents of $_FILES:
Array
(
    [upload_test] => Array
        (
            [name] => Scan.tiff
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )
)
```

Although we don't get the size of the file, we do know that it's exceeding the `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful to know, but what if you use the environment you described and then upload a file that's, say, 256 MB? You'll be back to the original problem. So I think whenever you use PHP to process file uploads, you have to implement something like [this](http://andrewcurioso.com/2010/06/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php/). But you did answer my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As with so many things, this constant can be traced back to a constant in the PHP source. In particular, [line 66 in rfc1867.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=316373&view=markup#l66).

It would seem that perhaps the person documenting the upload functionality was just copying and explaining each constant they saw registered in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Is to track the error when it `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

You can track the error using `error_get_last`, or the `try .. catch`