# Error UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; when try to upload a image using php to FTP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I made a script to upload from a form via php a foto to the FTP servers... but isnt work, when i used 
`$_FILES['userfile']['error'`] function
is return me the VALUE 1 which means `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.
but i spoke with the guys from the host company and they said is a max size fro 100mb, and i tried to uploade a image which has only 30kb, and also they tried to uploade using cPanel and its worked...

form code

```
<form action="foto-test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

foto-test.php

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp.xxxx.com";
$ftp_user_name = "xxx@xxx.com";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxx";
$destination_file = "/public_html/images/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file

if ($_FILES['file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
} 
else { echo !$upload;
}

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "  FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

the the message when i try to upload a image is

Connected to xxx, for user xxx **1** FTP upload has
 failed!
 so the **1** means UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive 
in php.ini.
but i have a lime fro 100 mb... so what is wrong? ?

**EDIT:// TOPIC CLOSED**, I fixed the problem, i had to modificied the `FTP_BINARY` with `FTP_ASCII` in the `ftp_put` statement

Comment: Not sure if this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300331/php-whats-the-point-of-upload-err-ini-size?rq=1

Comment: i didnt find answerd there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with the upload code ftp_put(), FTP_BINARY and nothing to do with the php.ini OR upload size, here is final code.

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp.xxxx.com";
$ftp_user_name = "ftpusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "ftppass";
$destination_file = "/public_html/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
exit; 
} else {
echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $destination_file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $destination_file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Indeed, i modificied FTP_BYNARY with FTP_ASCII and it works, thank you man, for helping me.

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a fault from their side. Documentation clearly states that the limit is defined by

upload_max_filesize - The maximum size of an uploaded file.

If you are sure that your POST_MAX_SIZE is less than UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE then contact them and tell them to check very carefully and see if it's really MB and not B.

Comment: post_max_size is 100mb and upload_max_filesize is 100mb ... so??