# How can i resolve upload_max_filesize issue

Tags: php, adsapi-php.ini

I have faced issue of `upload_max_filesize` , I have updated `php.ini` file on server with adding following.

```
memory_limit = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 900
upload_max_filesize =500M
```

[image]

Also I have updated .htaccess file like..

```
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors 
   php_value post_max_size 500M
   php_value max_execution_time 330
   php_value max_input_time 260
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 500M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
</IfModule>
```

But still i am getting same error `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini` , I just trying to upload `2MB` video but getting same error.

Why does it i happen i don't know , I have also words with server support center and they told me that they have set `500MB` max_upload_size.

Comment: you also need to edit this value in your php.ini file  'upload_max_filesize = 40M' . This will do the job.

Comment: @SumitKumar i have already added 500M in php.ini

Comment: What application are you using? Some CMS's have their own setting for this as well.

Comment: Please check script_filename in phpinfo shown above. It may happen that it may have different location or it is overwritten by any other means.

Comment: I am using core php not any CMS version 5+

Comment: `post_max_size` is too low. You can see in your screenshot it is 8M

Comment: @Pupil I have configure phpinfo on server and it's location is also correct, I have already checked.

Comment: Did You restart your web server after editing your php.ini file?

Comment: @Phil I have set 500M and we only trying to upload videos under 500MB so this size is enough for us.

Comment: Why does your screenshot show 8M then?

Comment: @Phil I'll look on this but i am trying to upload 2 MB video then why does error coming ? We are trying to upload max 5-6 MB videos not more size.

Comment: PHP does not generate any messages like _"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"_. A quick Google suggests that's a Wordpress error message. Are you sure you're not using a CMS like Wordpress?

Comment: @Phil I am not using wordpress , I am using core PHP and that error showing using $_FILES['file_name']['error']; If file is not uploaded then showing error message using this.

Comment: Pretty sure the `error` property is an integer. The message does not come from PHP. Find the code the produces that error and check the logic

Comment: @Phil , Please look this URL https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php, I am getting value of 1 integer it's UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE error

Comment: Like I said, it's an integer but your error clearly shows a string message. What is producing that message? What logic is it using to determine the error?

Comment: @Phil Yes i am getting integer value of 1 but you can see error message description over here https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php,

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300331/php-whats-the-point-of-upload-err-ini-size